# How to replace every element in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list

```
s:={1, 2, 4, 7, 8}
```

and I wish to replace every element in the list with `Range[Max[s]]`.

I know that I could replace every element individually using `ReplaceAll` by doing

```
Flatten[s /. {1 -> Range[Max[s]], 2 -> Range[Max[s]], 
   4 -> Range[Max[s]], 7 -> Range[Max[s]], 8 -> Range[Max[s]]}]
```

However, s is arbitrary, and I will be using this for lists much longer than s. I would like to be able to perform this with one command, rather than replacing each element individually.

I have tried

```
s /. s -> Range[Max[s]]
```

But this just returns the range once. I haven't been able to find anything about replacing every element of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this acceptable?

```
s={1, 2, 4, 7, 8};
Flatten[Map[Range[Max[s]]&,s]]
```

which is the same as

```
Flatten[Range[Max[s]]&/@s]
```

and both produce

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

which matches what your example code produces.

`Map` or `/@` will replace each item in the list with the result of a function applied to the item in the list. In your case the function doesn't depend on any individual item, but on the `Max` of the whole list. And the `&` turns `Range[Max[s]]` into a function. And the final enclosing `Flatten` gets rid of the nesting of the individual lists.

Does that help explain the thinking?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Using Replace(All) or Map is kinda slow for larger lists. Why not simply use:

```
ConstantArray[Range[Max[s]], Length[s]]
```

Answer (score 6):

With [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) you need a pattern to restrict the replacement or it will match the entire list:

```
Flatten[s /. _Integer -> Range[Max@s]]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, \
>  4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

---

### Performance

SHuisman's answer reminded me of performance.  If that is important consider [`PadRight`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadRight.html):

```
PadRight[Range[1], #*Length[s], Range@#] &[Max@s]
```

`Range[1]` is used instead of `{}` as the seed for `PadRight` because it creates a packed array.

Benchmark:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

fn1[s_List] := Flatten @ ConstantArray[Range[Max[s]], Length[s]]

fn2[s_List] := PadRight[Range[1], #*Length[s], Range@#] &[Max@s]

BenchmarkPlot[{fn1, fn2}, RandomInteger[9, #] &]
BenchmarkPlot[{fn1, fn2}, RandomInteger[#, 1*^5] &]
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: PadRight is surprisingly fast! Wow!  Flatten@, Join@@ or Catenate@ btw have quite different timings. but your PadRight stays faster…

Answer (score 3):

```
Mod[Range[Length[s] #], #, 1] & @ Max[s]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
>  8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

```
First @ ArrayReshape[Range @ #, {1, Length[s] #}, "Periodic"] & @ Max[s]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
>  8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
(* Not a one-liner, but easy enough to do so *)
s = {1, 2, 4, 7, 8};

l = Length[s];

item = Range[Max[s]]

Replace[s, {_ -> item}, {1}]  (* use level spec *)

(* Flatten if desired *)
```

Comment: `l = Length[s];` does not appear to be used?  Also consider `Cases[s, _ -> item]` as `Cases` defaults to a *levelspec* of `{1}`.